# Apache AB (ApacheBench) : -no-check-certificate option available?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http, benchmark, ab

It seems there is no option to avoid this error : "Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)". Is there a way to avoid issuer ssl check with AB (like wget's -no-check-certificate option)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: NO.

Related SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189993/how-do-i-fix-ssl-handshake-failed-with-apachebench contains some workarounds.

Comment: This is a joke, right? A performance test tool that doesn't let you  ignore SSL errors which are completely unrelated to performance?!